# How to solve: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Hello am facing a problem in android studio

I bought an app source code on codecanyon it's my first to use android studio so im not a developer on Java after import my project getting gradle downloading in the bar below  but after finished got this error

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

here is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()           
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()            
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

build.gradle inside folder app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.storeweb.crosswords"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 6
        versionName "2.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

[image: Image of The Error]

[image: Image of my CurrentAndroid Studio Version]

Comment: At least you can't use jcenter() any more. Use mavenCentral() instead.

Comment: @hata after i change it to mavenCentral() and sync  again Still the same problem

Comment: Can you go to the folder where build.gradle is , and use terminal and type ``` gradle build --debug ``` and share the base error , And consider reading the offical [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/troubleshooting.html#sec:troubleshooting_dependency_resolution) about troubleshooting dependency .

Comment: @George i did it and on android studio terminal via View=>Tools Windows=>Terminal and i got 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command same thing on cmd too

Comment: if you can follow [this](https://gradle.org/install/#:~:text=gradle%2D7.2%2Fbin-,Microsoft%20Windows%20users,Click%20OK%20to%20save.) to add it to your terminal , it would be easier to debug with .

Comment: Provide the full error log please.